# Firestore functions, onUpdate change other documents

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Im trying with a firebase function, onUpdate, to update 2 other documents.
This is my code:

```
exports.updateUserName = functions.firestore
    .document('users/{userId}')
    .onUpdate((change, context) => {
      const newValue = change.after.data().name;
      const previousValue = change.before.data().name;
     
      if(newValue != previousValue){

        admin
        .firestore("sets").where("authorId", "==", userId)
        .get()
        .then((querySnapshot) => {
          if (!querySnapshot.empty) {
            querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                doc.data().author = newValue
            });
          }
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log("Error changing Author name in sets", error);
        });

        admin
        .firestore("courses").where("authorId", "==", userId)
        .get()
        .then((querySnapshot) => {
          if (!querySnapshot.empty) {
            querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                doc.data().author = newValue
            });
          }
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log("Error changing Author name in courses", error);
        });

      }
    });
```

But I get an error: TypeError: _this.ensureApp(...).firestore is not a function
at FirebaseNamespace.fn (/workspace/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/firebase-namespace.js:239:45)  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`admin.firestore()` function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.firestore) returns a `Firestore` object. It *can* take an `app` parameter, but not a string describing the collection.

I think you're looking for:

```
admin
    .firestore().collection("sets").where("authorId", "==", userId)
    .get()
    ....
```

Comment: I think  this solved one error. Another problem is, that it seems like I cant just take the {userId} and use it as a userId variable right? How can I still access it?

Answer (score 0):

in an attempt to answer the more generic question in your header, but not your specific case (as i disagree with your datamodel being a relational-database-esque approach to firestore):

in firestore, use a field of type 'reference' instead of id's and foreign key merges.
say i have documents /users/{userid} and /courses/{course}, then I reference one or the other. For example in course/math201 i have a field author with a reference value of 'users/leo'

in my firebase function, i can use that reference to change different store objects, because the reference is of type firestore.DocumentReference, with handy built in functions.

Like in this example, with types and tsdoc:

```js
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
import {info, debug} from "firebase-functions/lib/logger";
import {firestore} from "firebase-admin";

const onUpdateCourse = functions
  .document('/courses/{course}')
  .onUpdate(updateCourse)

/**
 *  executed when a course changes
 * @param {functions.Change<functions.firestore.DocumentSnapshot>} change before and after snapshots
 * @param {functions.EventContext} ctx firestore context
 * @return {Promise<functions.firestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot>}
 */
async function updateCourse(
  change: functions.Change<functions.firestore.DocumentSnapshot>,
  ctx: functions.EventContext
) {
  // Unpack data
  const course = change.after.data();
  // Follow reference
  let user;
  if (course.author instanceof firestore.DocumentReference) user = (await course.author.get()).data()

  // Do something with both datasets as referenced
  debug('found course', course) // firestore.DocumentData | undefined
  debug('found author', user) // firestore.DocumentData | undefined
}

exports.onUpdateCourse = onUpdateCourse
```

Now update courses/math201 and you will be able to work with math201 and users/leo in your function and change either.